# why the status remain "new" everytime I refresh the page?

Tags: javascript, php, sql-update

I cant update the status no matter how hard i try, i had been stuck for more than two weeks in updating the status. the status change in the table but when i refresh the page, it remain "new". and it is also not being updated in the column statusid in tbl_apply

```
<span class="close">&times;</span>
<!-- Add your modal content here -->
<h3>Edit Status</h3>
<form id="editStatusForm" onsubmit="updateStatus(); return false;">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="newStatus">New Status:</label>
    <select id="newStatus" name="newStatus" class="form-control">
      <?php
      // Assuming you have a database connection established
      // Fetch the data from tbl_status table
      $status_query = "SELECT statuscat FROM tbl_status";
      $status_result = mysqli_query($con, $status_query);

      // Loop through the result and populate the dropdown options
      while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($status_result)) {
          $status = $row['statuscat'];
          echo "<option value='$status'>$status</option>";
      }
      ?>

    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Update</button>
```

```
// Make an AJAX request to update the status in tbl_apply
var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
  if (this.readyState === 4 && this.status === 200) {
    // Update the status details in the box
    var statusBox = document.getElementById("statusDetails");
    statusBox.innerText = newStatus;

    // Close the modal
    var modal = document.getElementById("editStatusModal");
    modal.style.display = "none";
  }
};
xhttp.open("POST", "update_status.php", true); // Replace "update_status.php" with the actual PHP script to update the status in the database
xhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
xhttp.send("newStatus=" + newStatus);
```

Comment: If that AJAX code is within the `updateStatus` function then the `submit` button will naturally try to submit the form in the regular manner so the AJAX will not be called unless you prevent that from happening

Comment: Without being redeclared, `newStatus` refers to the `HTMLSelectElement` defined in HTML. I would expect `"newStatus=" + newStatus` to evaluate to `newStatus=[object HTMLSelectElement]`, based on the code posted, which isn't useful. What do you want it to be (edit the question to show, please) and do you require help achieving that?

Comment: function updateStatus() {
// Get the selected value from the dropdown
var newStatus = document.getElementById("newStatus").value;